# Regex to all Validators except those which contains ValidationGroup

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010

I have tried to find all Validators in our project in Visual Studio 2010. Those are like that:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator
    ID="validator"
    runat="server"
    ErrorMessage="*"
    ControlToValidate="control"
    Display="Static"
    ValidationGroup="main">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

or

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator
    ID="validator"
    runat="server"
    ErrorMessage="*"
    ControlToValidate="control"
    Display="Static"
    ValidationGroup="main"
    Text="*"/>
```

I have tried with below validators with no results:

```
(\<asp\:[a-zA-Z]*Validator)~((.|\n)*ValidationGroup)(.|\n)*\/\>
(\<asp\:[a-zA-Z]*Validator)~(ValidationGroup)(.|\n)*(\<\/asp\:[a-zA-Z]*Validator\>)$
```

Do you see any bugs in them?

**EDIT:**

I have tried with below successfully (but only on site http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx):

```
\<asp\:[a-zA-Z]*Validator(?![^/]*ValidationGroup)[^/]*\<\/asp\:[a-zA-Z]*Validator\>
```

But when I replaced ?! with ~ it still doesn't work in Visual Studio.

But probably **mellamokb** posted correct answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I built this VS regex which seems to work for the first case:

```
(\<asp\:[a-zA-Z]*Validator)((:b|\n)+~(ValidationGroup)[a-zA-Z]+="[^"]*")+\>
```

I took your basic idea and searched for each attribute individually with the expression `(:b|\n)+[a-zA-Z]+\"[^"]*"`.  Then I search for multiples to grab all the attributes, and finally added a `~(ValidationGroup)` to prevent the matching from completing if any of the attributes are named ValidationGroup.

Comment: It looks like it works! Thanks, I will look into it more carefully later and probably mark your answer as correct one :)

Comment: I checked that and it works well, I really enjoy the idea of matching every property separately, nice catch ;) However I changed the part in matching property name to [^"=], because as far as I know properties could has also underline or digits in name and this one will match everything.

Comment: `(\<asp\:[a-zA-Z]*Validator)((:b|\n)+~(ValidationGroup)[^"=]+="[^"]*")+[\/]*\>` That one works for both cases. I have tried with other quantifiers to `[\/]*` but nor `?` nor `{0,1}` worked.

Comment: Put them in parenthese, `(\/)?`.  Otherwise you are checking the character class containing both `\ ` and `/`.

Answer (score 0):

This might work too.

```
  < [A-Za-z_:][\w:.-]*Validator
    (?=\s) 
    (?!
      (?:[^>"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*? (?<=\s)
      ValidationGroup \s*=
    )
    (?> \s+ (?:".*?"|\'.*?\'|[^>]*?)+ 
  >
    ) (?<= /> )
|
  < ([A-Za-z_:][\w:.-]*Validator)
    (?=\s) 
    (?!
      (?:[^>"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*? (?<=\s)
      ValidationGroup \s*=
    )
    (?> \s+ (?:".*?"|\'.*?\'|[^>]*?)+ 
  >
    ) (?<! /> )
  .*?
  </\1 \s*>
```